# Retrive queryset's related data

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-queryset, django-filter

I have the following model classes:

```
class User(models.Model):
    ...
class Book(models.Model):
    ...
class WishListRelationship(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, db_index=True, blank=False, null=False, related_name='wishlist', on_delete=CASCADE)
book = models.ForeignKey(Book, blank=False, null=False, on_delete=CASCADE)
created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

Then, from user I would like to get the queryset of books with a single call to database. If doing:

```
request.user.wishlist.select_related('book').all()
```

then I have the queryset of WishListRelationship, but I would like to get only books, so I've tried to do the following:

```
Book.objects.annotate(wished_books_ids=request.user.wishlist.all().values_list('book_id', flat=True)).filter(id__in=F('wished_books_ids'))
```

But I didn't achieve what I want, which is getting the list of related books in an INNER JOIN. How could I do that?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need to make it that complexs, you can query with:

```
Book.objects.filter(wish_list_relationship__user=request.user)
```

Comment: Awesome! That's exactly what I was looking for, thank you very much